# complex IF statement in assembly

Tags: if-statement, assembly, conditional-statements, x86

How should I write such an `if` statement in assembly?

```
if ((a == b AND a > c) OR c == b) { ...
```

Platform: Intel 32-bit machine, NASM syntax.

**Update**

For variable types and value, use whatever is more easy to understand. Integers would works fine for me, I guess.

Comment: What are the types of `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: Related: [double condition checking in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5196527) for range-checking one variable: `x > 10 && x < 100` for example.  And a common mistake of not realizing that execution falls through labels unless you use a branch instruction to make it go somewhere else: [Code executes condition wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32872539)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For a simple expression with no side effects (such as the one given), the order of evaluation does not matter<sup>(1)</sup>. That means you can check the "quick" cases first (those that decide with least code executed, `c == b` in this case).

In generic assembly, it will be basically something like this (assume `a` in `ax`, `b` in `bx`, `c` in `cx`):

```
    cmp  bx, cx     ; check b == c?
    jeq  is_true    ; final result is true.

    cmp  ax, cx     ; otherwise b != c, so check a <= c?
    jle  is_false   ; if so, final result is false.

    cmp  ax, bx     ; otherwise a > c, so check a == b?
    jeq  is_true    ; if so, final result is true.

is_false:
    ; do false bit  ; otherwise final result is false.
    jmp  next

is_true:
    ; do true bit

next:
    ; carry on
```

If there's no false bit, it can be simplified to something like:

```
    cmp  bx, cx
    jeq  is_true

    cmp  ax, bx
    jne  next      ; no false bit, next statement.

    cmp  ax, cx
    jle  next      ; no false bit, next statement.

is_true:
    ; do true bit

next:
    ; carry on
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> If the expression contained side-effects then order of evaluation may become important due to the possibility of short-circuiting evaluations. By that, I mean consider an expression such as (pseudo-code):

```py
if a == b and c == d:
    do_something()
```

In that case, once you establish that `a` and `b` are equal, there is no need to compare `c` and `d`.

I haven't covered that (other than in this footnote) since:

1. no source language was specified in the question (making it unclear whether it even *has* short-circuiting operations); and
2. the expression appears to have no side effects anyway.

Comment: I think it's good to point out here that in a language like C, the left side of the AND and OR would be evaluated first, and the right side may be skipped. If you want to write assembly for an if statement that matches C logic, you would have to change up the order here.

Comment: @jowo, I originally didn't worry about it since it wasn't clear what the source language was and there were no obvious side effects. However, have added a footnote to cover that case.

Answer (score 13):

You will need to break the if statement into a series of comparisons and jumps. In the same way that in C you could write:

```
int test = 0;

if (a == b) {
  if (a > c) {
    test = 1;
  }
}

// assuming lazy evaluation of or:
if (!test) {
  if (c == b) {
    test = 1;
  }
}

if (test) {
  // whole condition checked out
}
```

Which breaks the complex expression into constituent parts your asm will do likewise, although you can write it more cleanly in asm by jumping to the parts that are still relevant.

Assuming a, b and c are being passed to you on the stack (if they're not load them from elsewhere obviously)

```
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8] 
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+12] ; a == b?
        jne     .SECOND                 ; if it's not then no point trying a > c 
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+16] ; a > c?
        jg      .BODY                   ; if it is then it's sufficient to pass the
.SECOND:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+16]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+12] ; second part of condition: c == b?
        jne     .SKIP
.BODY:
        ; .... do stuff here
        jmp     .DONE
.SKIP:
        ; this is your else if you have one
.DONE:
```