# Code executes condition wrong?

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86, x86-16

Basic question here,

I wrote the following block:

```
    IDEAL
    MODEL small
    STACK 100h
    DATASEG

    Var1 db 4
    Var2 db 2

    CODESEG

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    xor ax, ax
    mov al, [Var1]
    cmp al, [Var2]
    jg  Var1Greater
    mov ax, 1
Var1Greater:
    mov ax, 0
```

I'm new to assembly.

I wanted to create a code that compares [Var1] to [Var2].

IF(!) [Var1] is greater than [Var2], execute `mov ax, 1`. IF(1) anything else(equal or less) excecute, `mov ax, 0`.

How can this be done? the code I wrote executes both instructions if the condition is true.

Comment: Related: [How to use jumps in assembly language to implement if conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72061257) has a good answer about how `if(cond){}else{}` translates into `if()goto` which is something you can do directly in asm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, Turbo Assembler "Ideal" mode;  It has been a while since I last saw it. I love Ideal mode.  It is so much better thought-out and it makes so much more sense than Microsoft Assembler's syntax.

Well, what is happening is that ***both*** instructions get executed.

First, `mov ax, 0` gets executed, and then control falls through to the next statement, which is `mov ax, 1`, so what you are left with in `ax` is `1`.

Labels in assembly language do not magically cause control to jump elsewhere.  They do not cause the assembler to emit any instructions.  They only exist so that you can indicate the target of another jump instruction.

So, what you need is:

```
    ...
    cmp al, [Var2]
    jg  Var1Greater
    mov ax, 0
    jmp skip
Var1Greater:
    mov ax, 1
skip:
```

also, it is good form when writing assembly language to use `xor ax, ax` instead of `mov ax, 0`.

Comment: Hey Mike, I understand this happens. But what is the correct way for making the code skip on the "Var1Greater" block because condition of "JG" didn't met?

Comment: Well, user4419802 was quicker than me, and he already gave the answer for that.

Comment: user4419802's answer is correct.  But if it does not fit your purpose, then what can I say, I amended my answer with a slightly different approach.

Comment: Why do you use `cmp ax, [var2]` since `var2` is defined as a byte? I'd probably expect your code to not compile. Maybe you meant `cmp al, [var2]`

Comment: Ah you are correct, the OP did change the question a bit in that regard. Your edit now matches. So all is good. And I upvoted.

Comment: The only foot note I can add to this all is that it is unclear if the OP knows that `jg` (jump greater) is a signed comparison and `ja` (jump above) is unsigned comparison. With `jg` if you make Var1=128 and Var2=127 they won't get the expected answer if they were assuming unsigned bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You must jump over `Var1Greater` too to skip `mov ax, 1` instruction. As alternative you may do it like:

```
mov ax, [Var1]
cmp ax, [Var2]
mov ax, 1
jg  skip0
mov ax, 0
skip0:
```

Comment: but if i do `mov ax, 1`, ax = 3. this is not what i was trying to get in the code.

Comment: @tilikompowaa `mov` doesn't change `flags` register, so it's safe to put it between `cmp` and `jg`.

Comment: but still if a=3 so skip0 will execute. I got pretty much confused here. Im just trying to create a simple "if" condition.

Comment: @tilikompowaa `skip0:` is not an instruction. It's just a label, a point where execution resumes _after_ the whole "pseudo-if-operator" is done.

Comment: I have changed the code to be more accurate about my question. please check.