# GCC emits a label that's not jumped to by anything outside that label?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc

Taking the following C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(unsigned char buffer[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        unsigned char data = buffer[i];
        printf("%c", data);
    }
}

void main() {
    unsigned char buffer[5] = "Hello";
    test(buffer, 5);
    return;
}
```

and compiling it the flags `-fno-stack-protector -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-unroll-loops` for clarity produces the following assembly for the `test()` function:

```
test:
    testl   %esi, %esi
    jle .L6
    pushq   %rbp
    leal    -1(%rsi), %eax
    pushq   %rbx
    leaq    1(%rdi,%rax), %rbp
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L3:
    movzbl  (%rbx), %edi
    addq    $1, %rbx
    call    putchar@PLT
    cmpq    %rbp, %rbx
    jne .L3
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L6:
    ret
    .size   test, .-test
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4
```

It seems to me like the `L3` label here is completely useless since it is never jumped to or entered.  (Except by `jne .L3`, but that instruction is inside of the L3 label already).

Can anyone explain how and why this assembly still produces the expected effect?

Comment: `jne .L3` seems to jump to it.

Comment: You might have found that location via simple text search functionality of your favourite editor...

Comment: `void main()`? I'm surprised you got that through the compiler at all. Are you compiling with or without optimization? Which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Depends, maybe he's on a bare micro controller ;)

Comment: the `jne .L3` is an instruction inside of the `L3` label though?

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah - but it's gcc so I thought it would refuse that - but it doesn't I now noticed when I tried it myself.

Comment: There is no "inside" to labels. They are just bookmarks. Also the cpu doesn't see them. You might be thinking the cpu stops before going through the `.L3`, it doesn't.

Comment: The code in L3 is entered from the code before it by continuing execution top to bottom... That p2align thing between produces a bunch of NOPs.

Comment: @TedLyngmo On my system: `../src/main.cpp:23:33: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’`

Comment: @dratenik oh that makes sense. I misunderstood the idea of labels. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, but this is in C mode and there it's a lot more flexible it seems [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vsnGnr36e)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Right, have been in the wrong file... `../src/main.c:28:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]` (`-Wall` enabled, not even pedantic).

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, OP should also add those. I recommend at least `-O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I always add `-Werror=implicit`, too.

Comment: No clue what seems to be the issue. The exact command i use to compile it is `gcc test.c -o test.out -O5 -fno-stack-protector -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-unroll-loops` which runs without error or warning on my linux box. As for the what Aconcagua said before, yes i'm writing some custom assembly for a microcontroller.

Comment: @DavinMiler I'd make use of the support for getting warnings for common mistakes no matter what the target platform is. `-Wall -Wextra` is the minimum I'd use to not let silly mistakes through which can ruin everything :)

Comment: There is no real issue.  ISO C allows `void main` for freestanding programs, and GCC doesn't complain about it for even for normal programs.  You compiled without `-ffreestanding`, but GCC (unlike g++) only warns about that with `-Wall` enabled. https://godbolt.org/z/aMfhsPM47. Still, you *should* compile with `-Wall` before posting code on SO, especially to ask questions about it, because *actual* weird compiler output (in other cases) may be the result of UB, or your C not meaning what you thought it meant, etc. And to avoid triggering OCD / distracting people with unrelated stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the assembler code from the top you will see that it reaches `.L3`, plus it also jumps to it with `jne .L3`, which is your `for` loop in C.

Comment: Yup, this is correct. For some reason i thought that execution would halt when reaching a label, which is obviously incorrect. I'll mark the post as solved.

Comment: @DavinMiler: [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926) covers the general case of loops in asm compiling this way.  [Code executes condition wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32872539) and [What if there is no return statement in a CALLed block of code in assembly programs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41205054) explain that labels are just symbolic names that let you refer to an address from elsewhere, nothing more, nothing less.