# Why is cmp always giving that the values are equal

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86-16

when i run this code then `success` is always called even when i enter other characters like v.

```
global start
section .text
start:
    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288     ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax
   

    call read_key
    call display
    
    cmp al, 'm'
    je success

    cmp al, 'M'
    je success
    

success:
    mov al, 'C'
    call display


read_key:
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push si
    push di
    mov ah, 0x00
    int 0x16
    pop di
    pop si
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    ret
display:
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push si
    push di
    movzx si, al
    mov ah, 0Eh
    int 10h
    pop di
    pop si
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    ret
```

Comment: What other did you expect? After `je success`the code falls through to `success`label. You nedd a goto instruction or an other branch.

Comment: so how to make that success is not executed by itself

Comment: Jump somewhere else if it's not `'M'`, instead of falling through into `success:`, as in [How to use jumps in assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72061257) and [Code executes condition wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32872539)

Answer (score 0):

If al is neither 'm' nor 'M', then the program counter would go down without branching to `success`. What do you see down there, `success:`