# I am stuck on solving the segmentation fault on the Nasm asm code for bits 32

Tags: c, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I am green with the asm programming. I have been trying to solve some tasks as way of learning. two of the tasks run well but two are failing with segmentation fault. I have gone through a lot of articles but I cant wrap my head around it.

here is my C driver

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


extern int is_palindrome(char *s);
extern void palindrome_check();

int is_palindrome(char *s){
int len=strlen(s);

    for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++){
        if(s[i] != s[len -i -1]){
        return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;

}

int main() {
   int choice;
   int result1;
   
   char str2[1024];

  do {
     printf("\nMenu:\n");
     printf("1) Test if a string is a palindrome (from C to ASM)\n");
     printf("2) Test if a string is a palindrome (from ASM to C)\n");
     printf("Enter your choice: ");
     scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
       printf("Enter a string: ");
       scanf("%s",str2);
      result1=is_palindrome(str2);
      if(result1==1){
         printf("It is a palindrome");
      }
      else {
         printf("It is NOT a palindrome");}
      break;

     case 2:
      palindrome_check();
      break;
     }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my functions.asm

```
BITS 32
extern is_palindrome

GLOBAL is_palindrome
GLOBAL palindrome_check

SECTION .bss
buf1 resb 1024
buf resb 1024

SECTION .data
    prompt db "Please enter a string:",0x0A
    lenprompt equ $ - prompt
    palindrome_msg db "It is a palindrome",0x0A
    lenpamsg equ $ - palindrome_msg
    not_palindrome_msg db "It is NOT a palindrome",0x0A
    lenntpamsg equ $ - not_palindrome_msg

SECTION .text
palindrome_check:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,prompt
    mov edx,lenprompt
    int 0x80

    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,buf
    mov edx,1024
    int 0x80

    push ecx

    call is_palindrome_c
    add esp,4

    cmp eax,1
    jne .palindrome_failed
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,palindrome_msg
        mov edx,lenpamsg
        int 0x80

    .palindrome_failed:
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,not_palindrome_msg
        mov edx,lenntpamsg
        int 0x80

is_palindrome:
    mov eax,[esp+4]
    mov [buf1],eax


    ;Calculate the length of the string
    xor eax,eax
    xor edi,edi
    mov esi,buf1

len_loop:
    inc eax
    inc esi
    cmp BYTE[esi],10
    je set_len
    jmp len_loop

set_len:
    dec eax
    mov [len1],eax

    ;For the palindrome check function
    mov ecx,eax
    mov ebx,buf1
    call is_palindrome_asm

is_palindrome_asm:
    mov eax,[len1]
    mov edi,eax
    xor ecx,ecx
    mov esi,ebx

palindrome_loop:
    cmp ecx,edi
    jae .done

    mov al,[esi+ecx]
    mov bl,[esi+edi]

    cmp al,bl
    jne .not_palindrome
    inc ecx
    dec edi
    jmp palindrome_loop

    .not_palindrome:
    mov eax,0
    ret

    .done:
    mov eax,1
    ret
```

To assemble the file I used the command:

```
nasm -g -f elf32 -F dwarf -o functions.o functions.asm
gcc -g -Wall -static -m32 -o backandforth backandforth.c functions.o
```

I have edited the code with regard to the corrections provided. The  any direction would help. Please note I said I am green, I gave the GEF debugger installed but I cannot make out what the error is. the palindrome_check does not exit with a segmentation fault error anymore, but every string I pass comes out as not a palindrome. I have tested the c function is_palindome_c and confirmed that it is working correctly.

Comment: First thing I notice is that right after `mov ecx,not_palindrome_msg`, you print the message, then drop right into the code that also prints that it *is* a palindrome.  Both of which then drop into the exit_program code.  Doesn't seem like what you intended.  Second thing is that when C calls asm, the compiler [assumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) that the asm will preserve certain registers (ie they'll have the same value after calling the asm that they had before).  Failing to follow this rule can easily result in segmentation faults.

Comment: Which instruction segfaults?  Use a debugger to check.  If it's not in your code, then you probably violated the ABI (e.g. by overwriting EBX, a call-preserved register in all standard calling conventions including i386 System V on Linux.)

Comment: This is far from a [mcve].  You have a whole menu thing and code for two of the options that call different asm functions that don't crash.

Comment: I was trying to provide as much information as possible since I dint know what is causing the problem

Comment: The point of a [mcve] is to reduce your code to something that still has the problem you're asking about, but does as little as possible while still triggering it.  The process of cutting your code down can sometimes narrow things down enough to solve it yourself, that's part of the point of requiring one.  See also https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ / https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/.  (See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for tips on using GDB for asm.  If you aren't using a debugger, that's your first problem; tons of different bugs lead to segfaults.)

Comment: Your question title still says it segfaults.  Looks like you haven't fixed the bug in `palindrome_check` that David pointed out, so it will print both messages for palindromes.  [Code executes condition wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32872539) .  (BTW, you just need to set ECX and EDX conditionally, the EAX, EBX and `int 0x80` are the same for both writes.)  Is that not what you're seeing? You say it only says it's not a palindrome? Perhaps because your string includes the newline the user entered?  A debugger should show you that's in `call is_palindrome_c`, which doesn't skip whitespace

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with the term "scoping?"  Cuz it seems likely your problem lies there.

Let's start with some C code first:

```
void codeA(void)
{
   int x = 5;
   codeB();
   printf("%d\n", x);
}

void codeB(void)
{
   int x = 6;
   printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

If you were to call codeA, what would you expect the output to look like?  codeB prints first, so it's going to print the 6.  But since it set `x` to 6, does that mean codeA will print 6 too?

No, of course not.  C 'scopes' each of the routines to have their own copy of x, so codeB's x doesn't overwrite codeA's copy.

However, things are a little different in assembler.  Registers have no scope.  If you set the ebx register to 5, then call a routine that sets it to 6, it's still 6 when it returns.

Scary, right?  If every time you call a subroutine it has the potential for changing the values of all of your registers, that could really make for a mess.  In order to be safe, it seems like you'd have to save all your registers before calling a function, then put them all back when you return.

While that could work, it would *really* slow down your code.  And it would be a huge and pointless waste of time if the function you are calling didn't actually overwrite any of your registers.

So instead, the people who make these decisions decided there would be  conventions that are followed when calling a function (appropriately enough called "calling conventions").  They would define some registers that the called routine was free to change at will.  If the callee changes any of the other registers, it must put the original value back before returning.

There are a number of different calling conventions out there.  Given that you are writing 32bit assembler code and calling it from C, the compiler for the C code will assume you are using the `cdecl` convention.  I linked to a description of it above, but [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) it is again.  The key point from that link is this:

> Registers EAX, ECX, and EDX are caller-saved, and the rest are callee-saved.

So when `main` calls `palindrome_check`, then main is the caller, and palindrome_check is the callee.  So what happens when palindrome_check does this:

```
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,prompt
mov edx,lenprompt
int 0x80
```

The caller has saved eax, ecx, and edx so you are free to change them however you like.  But what about ebx?  You (the callee) are changing it, which means when you return, the caller isn't going to have the value in ebx that it expects.  You broke the rules, and now bad things are happening as a result.

So, what can you do?  After all, you need to use ebx to print the string.  That's how int 0x80 works.  So what you need to do is save the old value, usually at the top of the called routine with something like this:

```
push ebx
```

Then at the bottom of the routine, just before you return, you can restore the original value with:

```
pop ebx
```

Looking at your code, you also modify other 'callee saved' registers (like edi).  They'll need to be saved too.

And there's a bit of a trick to it, so I'll save you from having to come back to ask the obvious next question.

If you push multiple registers:

```
push ebx
push edi
```

Then when you `pop` them, you need to do it in reverse order:

```
pop edi
pop ebx
```

Modifying 'callee saved' registers is (probably) what's causing your code to crash.

You also have another problem (that I mentioned above).  Looking again at codeA, what happens after it finishes the printf?  It hits the end of the routine and returns, right?

But assembly doesn't do that.  There is no "end of the routine," and indenting the code has no effect at all.  So after it finishes printing the first message, it just plows right on and executes the next instructions.

Probably what you need is a `jmp` to the end of the routine where you have your `pop` instructions followed by `ret`.

Comment: I talk a little bit more about calling conventions [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/133356/110050).  Might be a bit "in the weeds" for a beginner, but it might help clarify if you're still struggling to figure out what I'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

Your *palindrome_check* and *is_palindrome* codes are two different functions and you should cleanly separate them. Maybe use:

```
; --------------------------------------
is_palindrome:
```

### palindrome_check

Depending on the outcome of *is_palindrome_c* you should display one message and one message only. Currently you allow the 'is' code to fall through in the 'is not' code! A possible quick fix is to jump over the 'is not' code to the place where you exit the *palindrome_check* function with a `ret` instruction. (You can also just have `int 0x80` followed by `ret` on both occasions.)
But considering that the calling convention wants you to preserve EBX, I propose the following:

```
  mov  ecx, palindrome_msg
  mov  edx, lenpamsg
  cmp  eax, 1
  je   .msg
  mov  ecx, not_palindrome_msg
  mov  edx, lenntpamsg
.msg:
  mov  ebx, 1
  mov  eax, 4
  int  0x80
  pop  ebx                      ; Restore EBX
  ret
```

### is_palindrome

- This function has one argument which is a pointer to a string. You store it to memory but never use it again! The two times that you *think* you used it were written as `mov esi,buf1` but sadly that does not retrieve the pointer. In NASM this instruction rather loads the address of the *buf1* label. To obtain what is stored at *buf1* you need to dereference like in `mov esi, [buf1]` (much like you did for storing in the first place). This is probably the reason for your segmentation faults!
- The code that says it calculates the 'length of the string' can't cope with an empty string, needlessly stores to a memory-based variable named *len1*, and does not really store the actual length at all.
- In the lines

  > ```
  >     call is_palindrome_asm
  >
  > is_palindrome_asm:
  > ```

  the `call` to the label directly below is not needed. It just makes the *is_palindrome_asm* run twice. In this program it appears to be harmless but why would you do it like that?

What follows is my version of a palindrome checker.
I consider empty strings and one-character strings to be palindromes. Change at will...

```
is_palindrome:
        push  ebx            ; (1)
        mov   eax, 1
        mov   ebx, [esp + 8]
        mov   ecx, ebx
.find:  cmp   byte [ecx], 10
        lea   ecx, [ecx + 1]
        jne   .find
        dec   ecx            ; Make ECX point at newline
        jmp   .first
.next:  movzx edx, byte [ebx]
        cmp   dl, [ecx]
        jne   .not
        inc   ebx
.first: dec   ecx
        cmp   ebx, ecx
        jb    .next
        pop   ebx            ; (1a)
        ret                  ; EAX = 1
.not:   dec   eax
        pop   ebx            ; (1b)
        ret                  ; EAX = 0
```

**[edit]**

I don't use C myself, but doesn't C store strings with zero-termination? Your *is_palindrome* should therefore not look for **10** (C will have consumed it as an end-of-input signal), but rather for a **0**.

After a bit of profiling, I got this faster version that uses just EAX, ECX, and EDX. The local labels *.a:*, *.b:*, and *.c:* are to be 16-byte aligned.

```
is_palindrome:
        mov   ecx, [esp + 4]
        mov   edx, ecx

.a:     cmp   byte [edx], 0  ; Looking for the end-of-string marker
        lea   edx, [edx + 1]
        jne   .a
        sub   edx, 2         ; Make EDX point at last character
        cmp   ecx, edx
        jnb   .OK            ; Empty or 1-character string
        nop

.b:     movzx eax, byte [ecx]
        cmp   al, [edx]
        jne   .c
        inc   ecx
        dec   edx
        cmp   ecx, edx
        jb    .b
.OK:    mov   al, 1          ; Faster than `mov eax, 1`
        ret

.c:     xor   eax, eax
        ret
```

Remarkably, having `mov al, 1` for the *.OK:* case turned out to be 8% faster than `mov eax, 1`. I tested with a reasonably-sized string 'abcdefgfedcba' and had the caller inspect EAX:

```
...
call    is_palindrome    ; -> EAX (ECX EDX)
cmp     eax, 2
je      never_happens
...
```

Comment: If the goal is to set eax to zero, wouldn't `xor eax, eax` be more efficient than `dec eax`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Using `xor eax, eax` would have been more idiomatic, but as my initial intention with this code was to have but a single exit point for this function, I began by initializing EAX to 1 very early so that I could decrement to zero in the end. Whilst writing I must have changed my mind and I left the `dec eax` unintentionally where it was. Now, together with today's edit I verified this and found that performance-wise the `dec eax` is just as good as the `xor eax, eax`.