# How to efficiently conditional check multiple values in Assembly

Tags: assembly

Wondering how you accomplish this sort of thing in assembly (nasm x86 or anything).

```
if (a && (b || !c) && (d || e)) {
  something()
}
```

I am only beginning to learn about assembly so wanted to see how you would handle this "multiple variable" situation. You can't do (getting the `jnz` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196527/double-condition-checking-in-assembly)):

```
cmp eax, a && (b || !c) && (d || e)
jnz something
```

So it seems you would have to accumulate the value somehow.

Comment: you could manually use the Shunting-yard algorithm to solve such expressions to some rpn, which can be easily written as instructions. but keep in mind the difference between arithmetical and logical `and`/`or`/`xor`/etc. (see answer by Peter Cordes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every asm instruction in your source maps to at 1 machine instruction<sup>1</sup>.  Your assembler is not a compiler.

What you can do in one instruction depends completely on what the machine code can do; asm source syntax can express everything.  The x86 [`cmp` instruction](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html) can only read 2 input operands and write flags, so of course it can't set flags based on 6 inputs.

---

Sometimes you can efficiently turn a C source boolean expression into one asm branch, e.g. logical `||` can use a bitwise OR, which sets ZF based on the result being non-zero.  So `if(a || b || c)` could compile to

```
    or eax, ebx
    or eax, ecx
    jnz  .not_if

      ; if body
.not_if:
```

But more typically it's best to actually compare-and-branch on each part of the condition separately.  e.g. `if (a && b)` might compile to:

```
    test   eax,eax
    jz   .not_if
    test   ebx,ebx
    jz   .not_if

         ; if body    
.not_if:
```

You can't `test eax,ebx` because bitwise AND can be 0 with EAX=1 and EBX=2, for example.

Another case you can combine things into one cmp/jcc is range-checks: [double condition checking in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196527/double-condition-checking-in-assembly/5197264#5197264).  `sub` to bring one end of the range to `0`, then `cmp` / `ja` (unsigned compare).  Jumps if the `sub` wrapped to a large unsigned value, or if the value was out of range high.

More generally, look at what compilers do when compiling C.  Assignment to a `volatile` variable is a convenient thing to put in an `if()` body if you don't want the compiler to be able to turn the `if` into a branchless CMOV or something.  **See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for more about looking at compiler output and constructing useful compiler input.  Especially Matt Godbolt's CppCon talk**.

---

Actually creating booleans in integer registers and ANDing / ORing them together works on MIPS (which doesn't have a FLAGS register, so you either branch or compare into an integer register).

Or on POWER / PowerPC where there are multiple condition-code fields and you can compare into CR0, compare into CR1, then use a condition-register instruction to combine the conditions.

IDK if you forgot to tag x86, or if you were trying to ask a generic question about different assembly languages.

---

Footnote 1: Many RISC architectures have "pseudo-instructions" that expand to 2 or 3 actual machine instructions, like `li $t0, 0x1234567` on MIPS -> `lui` to set up the upper half of the 32-bit constant, and `ori $t0, $t0, 0x4567` to set the low half.  Fixed-instruction-width architectures can't fit an arbitrary 32-bit constant into one instruction the way x86 can.

x86 doesn't use "pseudo-instructions".  They're already complex enough. :P